# SQL Best way to JOIN day over day data into same row including new and deleted IDs

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I initially thought this would be fairly simple but for some reason I'm struggling with it.

If I have a table that looks like this:

```
table1
Date        ID       Quantity
2/21        1        100
2/21        2        500
2/21        3        200
2/20        2        600
2/20        3        400
2/20        5        2000
```

And I want to join this data to look like:

```
ID        prev_date     prev_quantity    curr_date     curr_quantity
1         2/20          0                2/21          100
2         2/20          600              2/21          500
3         2/20          400              2/21          200
5         2/20          2000             2/21          0
```

The tricky part being ID 1 doesn't have an entry for previous day (so make 0) and ID 5 doesnt have an entry for current day (make that 0 as well)

What is the best way to do this?  Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I appreciate everyones help on this, but I'm not sure if I'm explaining this incorrectly.  None of these solutions are working, only one remotely close is the one from @sureshhh - but even that is missing the rows/ids that exist for the min date and not max date.  **Im just looking to create 1 row for each unique ID that exist in either day.**  Maybe I over complicated the question?  Thanks again for any feedback on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help u,,,,,

```
SELECT 
    ISNULL(T.ID,T1.ID),
    ISNULL(T.DATE,GETDATE()) AS 'CurrDate',
    ISNULL(T.Quantity,0) AS 'CurrQty',
    ISNULL(T1.DATE,GETDATE()-1) AS 'PrevDate' ,
    ISNULL(T1.Quantity,0) AS 'PrevQty'
FROM 
    (   
        SELECT 
              T.ID,
              T.Quantity,
              T.DATE 
        FROM @TABLE T   
        WHERE T.DATE = CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),100)   
    )T
    FULL OUTER JOIN 
    (
      SELECT 
            T1.ID,
            T1.Quantity,
            MAX(T1.DATE) AS [DATE] 
      FROM @TABLE T1 
      WHERE   T1.DATE <> CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),100)
      GROUP BY  T1.ID,T1.Quantity
    ) T1 ON T.ID = T1.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  curr.ID, ISNULL(Prev.date, DATEADD(DD, -1, curr.Date)) AS Prev_Date,        
        ISNULL(prev.Quantity, 0) AS Prev_Quantity, 
        ISNULL(curr.date, DATEADD(DD, 1, prev.Date)) AS Curr_Date, ISNULL(curr.Quantity, 0) AS Curr_Quantity
FROM    table1 curr
            FULL OUTER JOIN
        table1 prev
        ON curr.ID = prev.ID AND prev.Date = DATEADD(DD, -1, curr.Date)
```

Comment: You beat me too it, mine looks more or less identical to yours except I had the ID within an Isnull as well since you'll get NULLs for `curr.ID` sometimes. Since they are supposed to equal eachother on the JOIN or be NULL it seems safe to do `Isnull(curr.ID,prev.ID)`.

Comment: Thanks I will try this out - but what if the day to day isn't always 1 day difference, there could be gaps for like weekends, holidays?  I should have parameters for @ CURRDATE and @ PREVDATE so I can probably just plug those in instead of the dateadds? thanks again

Comment: Not using DateAdd would mean you need to either specify which dates to join (which will let you do only 1 set a time), or you'll need a separate table in which the date->previous date relationships are set. A table like that could also be created using your existing data by using a query. It just depends on what your data looks like. IE, if you have a list of hundreds of days with gaps here and there, the second option of creating a date mapping sub query would be best.

Comment: The query above is returning too many rows.  It should just return a row for every unique ID.  In my case about 600 rows.  When I run this query it gives me about 1800 rows.  For each ID I'm getting 3 rows.  1 row seems correct.  2nd row has prev_date and curr_date = '2/20/2014' and 3rd row has null ID with prev_date and curr_date = 2/21/2014 thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

You could solve the gaps problem using a rank. Also instead of ISNULL use a UNION:

```
SELECT RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ID,DATE) rank, ID, date, quantity
INTO temp1
FROM (
SELECT date, ID, quantity
          FROM table1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT dateadd(day,-1,MIN(date)) date, ID, 0 quantity
          FROM table1
          GROUP BY ID
        UNION ALL
        SELECT dateadd(day,1,MAX(date)) date, ID, 0 quantity
          FROM table1
          GROUP BY ID
)  AS U;

SELECT p.ID, p.date prev_date, p.quantity prev_quantity, 
             c.date curr_date, c.quantity curr_quantity
FROM temp1 p INNER JOIN temp1 c ON c.rank = p.rank + 1 AND c.ID = p.ID
```